# How to use split to have a new columns

Tags: python

movies

```
| Movies | Release Date |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens (2015) | December 16, 2015            |
| Avengers: Endgame (2019   | April 24, 2019               |
```

I am trying to have a new column and use split to have the year.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Movies': ['Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens (2015)', 'Avengers: Endgame (2019'], 
                   'Release Date': ['December 16, 2015', 'April 24, 2019' ]})    
movies["year"]=0
movies["year"]= movies["Release Date"].str.split(",")[1]
movies["year"]
```

TO BE

```
| Movies | year |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens (2015) | 2015            |
| Avengers: Endgame (2019)   | 2019            |
```

BUT

```
> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: Please check [ask] and post [mre] as well as full traceback. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.extract` we can target the 4 digit year:

```py
df["year"] = df["Release Date"].str.extract(r'\b(\d{4})\b')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

1. `movies["Release Date"].str.split(",")` returns a series of of the lists returns by `split()`
2. `movies["Release Date"].str.split(",")[1]` return the second element of this series.

   This is obviouly not what you want.

### Solutions

- Keep using `pandas.str.split`. but then a function that gets the 2nd item of the series rows for example:

  `movies["Release Date"].str.split(",").map(lambda x: x[1])`
- Do something different as suggestted by @Tim Bielgeleisen